# C++ understanding integer overflow

Tags: c++

After solving some C++ problems from LeetCode I came across to the [Reverse Integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) and realized I can not really grasp how to deal with integer overflow.

The problem is simple and consists in reversing an integer number (e.g. 123 -> 321). Now, the difficult part is complying with the following limitation:

> Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2<sup>31</sup>,  2<sup>31</sup> − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 0 when the reversed integer overflows

What I did was the following:

```
int reverse(int x) {
   int temp = 0;
   while(x != 0){
       // pop
       int pop = x%10;
       x /= 10;

       if(temp < (INT_MIN - pop)/10 || temp > (INT_MAX - pop)/10){
          return 0;
       }
       else{
           // push
           temp = temp*10 + pop;
      }
   }

   return temp;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code does not prevent the overflow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(INT_MAX + pop)` overflows

Comment: @HongOoi could you elaborate?

Comment: You can't use an overflow to fix an overflow. If you check whether something is bigger than `INT_MAX`, it's never going to be because `INT_MAX` is, *by definition*, the biggest.

Comment: Look at the negative overflow! You did the same analogously: You added something to make the most negative one a bit greater – so that you again could subtract something. Analogously now for the positive, you need to make it a bit smaller so that you can add a bit more again, so you need to *subtract* from INT_MAX...

Comment: @Evg you're right, my mistake when copying the code... I'll re-edit my question.

Comment: @eduardogfma now `INT_MIN - pop` underflows.

Comment: Significant edits of questions are problematic notably for code: answers could refer to the old version. Please don't change your code such that answers are invalidated; if you want to fix code, label the versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sign of `pop` is implementation-defined (before C++11), and `INT_MIN - pop` will cause an overflow if it is negative. So let's first reduce the problem to positive integers only:

```
if (x == INT_MIN)    // INT_MIN cannot be inverted, handle it separately
    return 0;
const int sign = (x < 0) ? -1 : 1;
x *= sign;
```

The overflow condition is:

```
10 * temp + pop > INT_MAX
```

After simple math, we get:

```
temp > (INT_MAX - pop) / 10
```

Here `pop` is always non-negative, so `INT_MAX - pop` cannot overflow. The final result is `sign * temp`. Because  `temp` is positive, `-temp` cannot overflow (it could overflow if `temp` were negative).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the following notation ```const int sign = (x < 0) ? -1 : 1;```? What does the `?` does? It's my first time seeing such a notation. Does it define `-1` for `false` and `1` for `true`, is it?

Comment: @eduardogfma, exactly. It's called a ternary conditional operator.

Comment: @eduardogfma, correction: `-1` for `true`, `1` for `false`. Sign of `sign` = sign of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was bad logic. Since `temp` is initialised to `0`, there is no need for the `pop` to enter the condition. Thus, it suffices to write `if(temp < (INT_MIN)/10 || temp > (INT_MAX)/10)`.

The final code is as follows,

```
int reverse(int x) {
   int temp = 0;
   while(x != 0){
       // pop
       int pop = x%10;
       x /= 10;

       if(temp < (INT_MIN)/10 || temp > (INT_MAX)/10){
          return 0;
       }
       else{
           // push
           temp = temp*10 + pop;
      }
   }

   return temp;
}
```

Comment: 1) For negative integers `x % 10` can be positive. Its sign is implementation defined, and you can't rely on it being negative. (I suppose your goal is to write correct programs, and not just get the "Success" result on LeetCode.) 2) In general, you need `pop` in the condition. Consider the case when `temp = 214748364` and `pop = 8`: the condition `temp > (INT_MAX) / 10` is `false`, but `temp * 10 + pop` overflows. Yes, you can't have `8463847412` as an input, but suppose you work with 64-bit signed integers. You code will cause an overflow for `x = 8085774586302733229` (`<= INT64_MAX`).

Comment: @Evg I appreciate the comment, and of course I am interested in getting correct code. Actually, what I was really hoping to learn was about overflowing in C++, I wasn't that interested in LeetCode, they just have interesting problems. Anyway, could you elaborate on the 1st point? How is it possible for `x % 10` to return a positive integer for negative `x`?

Comment: Let `a = -3` and `b = 2`. What is `a % b`? The definition is: `(a / b) * b + a % b == a`. What is `a / b`? In C++11 the rule is: "the fractional part is discarded", so the value is `-1`, and `(-3) % 2 == -1`  for all standard-conforming implementations. But before C++11 there is no such rule, rounding is implementation-defined, so we could have `(-3) / 2 == -2`. Then we would have `(-3) % 2 == 1`. I can't name any implementation that would give this result, but you can't rely on what is not in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I find showing the Two’s Complement representation on a disc very helpful.

Here is a representation for 4-bit integers. The maximum value is **2^3-1 = 7.**

For 32 bit integers, we will see the maximum value is **2^31-1**.

When we add 1 to **2^31-1** :  Clockwise we move by one and it is clearly **-2^31** which is called integer overflow

In your case, the overflow happens when you have reverse of 2^31, when you reverse that you need to get 2^31, but it does not exist and you need to return 0 (as asked in the question instructions)

[image]

Ref : https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse351/17wi/sections/03/CSE351-S03-2cfp_17wi.pdf